# Optimize python dictionary creation for counting substring occurrences

Tags: python, fasta

The function receives the name of a file containing thousands of lines and a K value.
The function must divide each line of the file in K sequences and create a dictionary in which the sequence is the key and the value is the number of times that is present in the file.
**The problem is that it takes a long time (75s).**

```
def dictionary_creator(file, k):
    dictionary = dict()
    for record in SeqIO.parse(file, "fasta"):
        for i in range(len(record.seq) - k + 1):
            kseq = str(record.seq)[i:i + k]
            if kseq in dictionary:
                dictionary[kseq] += 1
            else:
                dictionary[kseq] = 1
    return dictionary
```

EXAMPLE:

sampleC.fa

> D00535:66:CCE77ANXX:5:2306:5138:1999 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+GTACTGAC
>   AGTCTGAGTAGCGTCGTGGTATTCCTGAAAGGNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNNNNTGTTATGTTTACTCCTACGAATNTGATGGCGAAGTGGGCTNTTGCT
>   D00535:66:CCE77ANXX:5:2306:6815:1999 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+GTACTGAC
>   GATGATCTGCCGAAGCTCAGGAATTCGGTCGTNNNNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNNNNNCTCTGGTCCAGCCTTTCCACGTNCTCCACTCGCATGCCGANGATGA
>   D00535:66:CCE77ANXX:5:2306:17450:1999 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+GTACTGAC
>   GGCTTCATGCTGCAGCGTGGCCTCCTCCAGGTNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNNNNGCCTCTCTCTTCTTGTTCATCTNGATCTGGGCTGAAGTGGNNCCGC
>   D00535:66:CCE77ANXX:5:2306:18797:2000 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+GTACTGAC
>   AAGCTGTTAGTGAAATAAATGATCCTATAGAANNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNGNNAGCATCTGGGTAGTCTGAGTAGNGTCGTGGTATTCCTGAANGGCCC
>   D00535:66:CCE77ANXX:5:2306:1210:2146 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+GTACTGAC
>   GTCATGTCTTCCTTTTCAAAAAACTTCAGTTTTGTAGATTTTCGTTGAAACAGCAAGCGAAGCACCAGGTCCTCTCTTCTCATCGGAGCGTCTGCAGATCG

Python:

```
dictionary_creator('sampleC.fa',2)
```

output:

```
{'AG': 26, 'GT': 31, 'TC': 42, 'CT': 38, 'TG': 32, 'GA': 24, 'TA': 13, 'GC': 25, 'CG': 18, 'GG': 20, 'AT': 22, 'TT': 27, 'CC': 20, 'AA': 23, 'GN': 5, 'NN': 79, 'NT': 6, 'TN': 9, 'AC': 7, 'CA': 19, 'NG': 7, 'NC': 3, 'AN': 3, 'NA': 1}
```

Comment: what functionality does `k` have in your function?

Comment: How large is the resulting dictionary? I doubt it is the actual dictionary creation that takes a long time, but rather, something else you are doing.

Comment: It is probably the i/o operation that takes most of the time, not the dictionary creation itself.

Comment: You are creating a large string inside the loop; you could hoist that out. You can probably slice more efficiently, too, and use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking this against a simple shell version?  `fold -w2 filename | sort | uniq -c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trivial improvement to make: you're doing `str(record.seq)` in the inner loop. This operation takes O(n) time where n is the length of the string, and you're doing it O(n) times, so the time complexity of the algorithm O(n²). But the string is the same each time, so you should just build it once in the outer loop:

```py
    for record in SeqIO.parse(file, "fasta"):
        seq_str = str(record.seq)
        for i in range(len(seq_str) - k + 1):
            kseq = seq_str[i:i + k]
            # ...
```

After applying this fix, this straightforward algorithm has a running time of O(nk) where n is the length of the string, and k is the length of the substrings you want to count. If that's good enough, then great, you can stop reading here.

---

A more efficient solution is possible using a [suffix automaton](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html), which is the smallest [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) accepting all suffixes of the string:

> Intuitively a suffix automaton can be understood as compressed form of all substrings of a given string. An impressive fact is, that the suffix automaton contains all this information in a highly compressed form. For a string of length n it only requires O(n) memory. Moreover, it can also be build in O(n) time (if we consider the size k of the alphabet as a constant), otherwise both the memory and the time complexity will be O(n log k).

The idea is to construct a suffix automaton for `record.seq`, and then use it to count occurrences for every possible substring of length k.

It takes O(n) time to [build the suffix automaton](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html#toc-tgt-3), and then O(k) time to [count occurrences for each substring](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html#toc-tgt-20). There are a^k possible substrings, where a is the size of the alphabet (5 in your example), so the overall running time for your problem will be O(n + 5^k). If n is quite a lot larger than 5^k, then this could be a significant speedup; but almost certainly not if k is very small.

Comment: the first solution is already very efficient, I'll also try with suffix automation to see if it's even better